# Onsen UI Carousel getActiveCarouselItemIndex() not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

Hi I am trying this code :

```
<ons-carousel var="cardays" ng-model="myform.day" ng-init="on('postchange',console.log('yay!!!'));" swipeable style="margin-top: 5px; height: 70px;" overscrollable auto-scroll >
  <ons-carousel-item  ng-repeat="dayitem in daylist">
    <div>{{dayitem}}</div>
  </ons-carousel-item>
</ons-carousel>
```

in app.js (model)

```
console.log(cardays);
```

I am trying to get `getActiveCarouselItemIndex()` by

```
console.log(cardays.getActiveCarouselItemIndex())
```

which is not working.

`console.log` say `cardays` is `undefined`.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In Onsen UI 1.2.1 there is a bug that makes the initialization of carousel to be delayed. In Onsen 1.2.2 (that was released today) this has been fixed.

If you still want to use 1.2.1 you can use `setImmediate()` to wait for it:

```
setImmediate(function() {
  console.log(cardays.getActiveCarouselItemIndex());
});
```

You can download the new version from http://onsen.io/ or using install it using bower.

Comment: Well I tried your code with Onsen UI 1.2.1 - it dint worked - then I updated Onsen UI to 1.2.2  - it was not working - until I applied setImmediate()